# how to find the substring javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string something like `var myStr = 'Foo Faa {{Foo1234Faa789863Whateva}}'`. I don't know what is there between the braces and I want to find out substring `'{{Foo1234Faa789863Whateva}}'` by doing something like `myStr.search('{{anycharacter}}')`. Please help me how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
var myStr = 'Foo Faa {{Foo1234Faa789863Whateva}}'
var match = myStr.match(/{{(.*)}}/)
if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: simple, just need to know how to react if you found {{Foo1234Faa789863Whateva}}{{Foo1234Faa789863Whateva}} or {{Foo1234Faa789863Whateva {{Foo1234Faa789863Whateva}} }} to update your code. If the OP needs it of course ;)

Comment: Since the OP didn't mention anything about nesting. I think it is safe to assume that it is not needed.

Comment: Yeah, I just hope he will read my comment and update if needed ;)

Answer (score 2):

Addition to @SGSVenkatesh's answer

`match()` is a pretty good choice, but if you know that only the first match is what you want, you can use 2 `split()` functions instead match.

```
var myStr = 'Foo Faa {{Foo1234Faa789863Whateva}}';
var strSplit = myStr.split("{{");
var strSplit2 = strSplit[1].split("}}");
console.log(strSplit2[0]);
// logs "Foo1234Faa789863Whateva"
```

You can make it into a function as;

```
function getFirstMatch(beginsWith, endsWith, myStr){
    var strSplit = myStr.split(beginsWith);
    var strSplit2 = strSplit[1].split(endsWith);
    return strSplit2[0];
}
//usage

console.log(getFirstMatch("{{", "}}", "Foo Faa {{Foo1234Faa789863Whateva}}"));
// logs "Foo1234Faa789863Whateva"
```

It just feels more efficient for me, did not do any test about which is better, post a comment if you do performance test ;)